# Accidentally set expires max in http block

Tags: nginx, cache

Yesterday, I accidentally set max expires option in http block.
What should I do to clear client cache ?

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for my rails server (unicorn), rails has a asset digest at the end of static file, except (maybe) html files.

Some clients still experiencing wrong-cache in their browser, how do I solve this ? is there any approach I can take to clear client's browser cache ?

P.S: I've been re-deploy my rails apps, restart rails server, and set expires -1; in nginx.conf.

Thank you.

Comment: If your headers are such that clients aren't sending validation requests - then there are 2 ways: change the url or get users to clear their browser cache. Redeploying, or anything server side won't do anything if clients are not communicating with your server at all. [reference](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#defining-optimal-cache-control-policy).

Comment: 1. Do you mean change the base url ? Because I set expires max in http block, so basically it has already cache all pages. 
2. How do I force client's browser to clear their cache ?
Thank you.

Comment: 1. No 2. You ask/tell them. The only way you can do anything from the server is get users to access a different url.